# How to print console output into my website Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'll create my own logs in Ruby On Rails, because my application don't generate logs. (I don't know why). How I can puts what user done in database? F.e if user add sth to database i'll have some output in admin page. I have done special roles so I have special page to admin view.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: you want log file will be shown in view ?

Comment: If I add sth into database via website in console I have some output and I'll show it in my website

Comment: I'll only this what SQLITE print in my console (rails c)

Comment: I edited my question to specify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a page that reads the content of the /log/production.log and displays it. That page will have a authorization rule so only admin can access it.

Comment: but I have problem with log files - they are empty all the time

Comment: Make sure you have config.log_level = :debug in your /config/environments/production.log file.

If you're running your app on development mode the log you should look at is /log/development.log